# How to disable "new network interfaces have been detected" prompt on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, network, system-settings, thunderbolt-display

I get this uber annoying prompt every single time I plug my Macbook Air into my Thunderbolt display. Does anyone please know of a way to disable this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences/Network and accept said interface as you own.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the interface can be accepted in *System Preferences/Network*. In my case there was no interface to accept. If the interface does not appear in the *System Preferences* the interface can still be created using the the command line command `networksetup -detectnewhardware`. This will require administrator privileges and create the interface.